# How to stop real time antivirus in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I switched tamper protection off, edited group policy, rebooted quite a few times, and yet Windows 10 *still* switches it back after about a day or so. How could I stop this? (Version 10.0.18362.657)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried all [these methods](https://learn.g2.com/how-to-turn-off-windows-defender)?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-real-time-protection-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: @Mark thanks for the warning, I added a second screenshot.